# Optional parameters in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, optional-parameters

I'm writing some [stored procedures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) in SQL Server 2008. Is the concept of optional input parameters possible here?

I suppose I could always pass in NULL for parameters I don't want to use, check the value in the stored procedure, and then take things from there, but I was interested if the concept is available here.

Comment: Take a long read at Erland's site, he has some great info on dynamic search conditions: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Answer (score 286, accepted):

You can declare it like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcName
    @Parameter1 INT = 1,
    @Parameter2 VARCHAR (100) = 'StringValue',
    @Parameter3 VARCHAR (100) = NULL
AS

/* Check for the NULL / default value (indicating nothing was passed) */
if (@Parameter3 IS NULL)
BEGIN
    /* Whatever code you desire for a missing parameter */
    INSERT INTO ........
END

/* And use it in the query as so */
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Column = @Parameter
```

Comment: what if the parameter is type of uniqueidentifier? ex. @userId uniqueidentifier

Comment: Answering @RKSharma for anyone who's wondering too - it works just the same with uniqueidentifiers.

Answer (score 77):

Yes, it is.  Declare the parameter as so:

```
@Sort varchar(50) = NULL
```

Now you don't even have to pass the parameter in.  It will default to NULL (or whatever you choose to default to).

Comment: You don't even need the `= NULL`

Comment: Are you sure you don't need it?

Comment: OMG Ponies, if you don't include = <NULL|some default value>, then the parameter will be required.  You can pass it in as NULL, but then you just shift that logic to the application(s) that use the procedure.

Comment: Adding to Aaron's point. It is better to use the " = NULL" if you are adding a new optional parameter to an existing stored proc. The reason is, you may not be aware of ALL the code that calls this proc. Hence, unless you make it optional using the " = NULL", for all the places that you may have missed to pass in a value, it will break.

Comment: nanonerd: 2014 and above at least you can set a default and it will take that and NOT error when you do not pass that parameter.  At least that's the way it worked for me in 2014 with

Answer (score 9):

In [SQL Server 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2014) and above at least, you can set a default, and it will take that and *not* error when you do not pass that parameter.

Partial example: the third parameter is added as optional. Execution (`exec`) of the actual procedure with only the first two parameters worked fine.

```
exec getlist 47,1,0

create procedure getlist
   @convId int,
   @SortOrder int,
   @contestantsOnly bit = 0
as
```

Comment: Sweet! Last time I tried this was with Sql 2012, and back then, it still required you to pass in NULL to get the default value. Nice to know they finally took out that requirement and made them truly **optional** .

Answer (score 3):

The default mentioned in previous answers only works for simple cases. In more complicated cases, I use an IF clause near the beginning of the stored procedure to provide a value, if the parameter is NULL or empty and calculations are required.

I often use optional parameters in the WHERE clause, and discovered that SQL does not short circuit logic, so use a CASE statement to make sure not to try to evaluate NULL or empty dates or unique identifiers, like so:

```
CREATE Procedure ActivityReport
(
    @FromDate varchar(50) = NULL,
    @ToDate varchar(50) = NULL
)

AS

SET ARITHABORT ON

IF @ToDate IS NULL OR @ToDate = '' BEGIN
    SET @ToDate = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101)
END

SELECT ActivityDate, Details
FROM Activity
WHERE
1 = CASE
   WHEN @FromDate IS NULL THEN 1
   WHEN @FromDate = '' THEN 1
   WHEN ActivityDate >= @FromDate AND ActivityDate < DATEADD(DD,1,@ToDate) THEN 1
   ELSE 0
END
```