# Default Equivalent to DBNull.Value

Tags: c#, sql, null, default

I am trying to pass default to SQL Server in c#.

This code passes null. Is there any way to pass default?

```
foreach (SqlParameter Parameter in command.Parameters)
{
    if (Convert.ToString(Parameter.Value) == "")
    {
        Parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this kind of what you mean? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810638/optional-parameters-in-sql-server-stored-proc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810638/optional-parameters-in-sql-server-stored-proc) By assigning the parameter in the stored procedure, you don't even have to pass that parameter if you want to use the default value you assigned it in the procedure definition.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not really what I meant, though. I am looking to pass the SQL reserve word 'default' from c# somehow. I don't really know how to do it, and there is no DBDefault.Value (because that, of course,  would be too easy). I also don't know if it's possible. I've been researching it for a couple hours.

Comment: Ah I see now. I'll see if I can come up with something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution of sorts -- it appears to search the stored procedure for parameter default values (literally, a pattern search for the assignment in the declaration of the variable), and return any default values that are found.  So...you could call *this* procedure from your c# app to get all of your default values, assign them to local C# vars, and then use them when you call your other procedure.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12939/Figure-Out-the-Default-Values-of-Stored-Procedure

And here is how you could find the default value on a table itself:
(you might need to strip the parenthesis off the returned value)

```
SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT, replace(replace(COLUMN_DEFAULT,'(',''),')','') as DefaultWithNoParenthesis
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'WHATEVER'
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Either don't add the parameter, or add the parameter but set the value to `null` (***not*** `DBNull.Value`). Both have the same effect: the parameter is not passed, therefore the default is used.

Comment: Like this: Parameter.Value = null; ?

Comment: I got this error message: PS_DOC_HDR insertion failed. Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'RS_STAT', table 'TestGolf846.dbo.PS_DOC_HDR'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. By the way, 'RS_STAT' has a default value in SQL of 1. Let me  know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: @IanBest the "default" here only goes as far as the parameter value. There is no such thing as a value that means "use the underlying table's default value". Presumably, the *parameter*'s default value here is: `null`. So your insert statement has tried to insert `null` into a column that *doesn't allow null*. Have you tried making the parameter's default value mimic the column's default? for example `@foo int = 1` ?

Comment: I got it all figured out using an entirely different approach. I don't think what I was looking to do is possible in c#. Thank you for your time, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the parameter default in SQL-Server (Stored Procedure...)

```
(@parm varchar(5) = null)
AS
Begin...
```

And then don't pass the parameter from C# at all.

Comment: The procedure is already stored, I just want to be able to handle defaults at the SQL level without having to really deal with it in my code. Right now, I am using individual if statements to set all the values to defaults.

Comment: Default value could be established at different levels.  At the table design level, which you would use by not setting or changing a value for the field; at the stored procedure level, in which case you need to say `@parm <type> = null`, and then don't pass the parameter from your code; or else in your code, by creating a constant (or whatever) with the value you wanted to use as your default.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll just have to stick with what I'm doing. I appreciate the help.