# T-Sql condition check

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table where there is column called `allocated_to`. If there is a value in that column, that means the status of the row is `assigned` otherwise `unassigned`.

From my search box i am sending `1` for `assigned` and `0` for unassigned. Also I have two more similar checks for `pending` and `closed` on column named `SignOff (type: int)`.

Now we have total of 9 search criteria

```
1. Pending
2.Closed
3. Unassigned
4. Assigned
5. Pending + Unassigned
6. Pending + Assigned
7. Closed + Unassigned
8. Closed + Assigned
9. For all records irrespective of any statuses.
```

So How do I add condition to my query. Actually its a change in SP and SP for that is already up and running. So I cant make a huge change in my query, by making it dynamic or whatsoever.

I can give you a sample here , how my query looks like:

```
If Some_Condition
 begin
   Select x,y,zfrom T1 join T2 on t1.a=t2.b
   Where IsNull(SignOff,0)=@ParamForPendingAndClosed
 end
```

Now I would like to add my above 9 check in this where, Any help??

**Please note:**

I can't take heavy alterations, as I need it to make in each and every if-else condition. Query has almost 4-5 if else depending upon its header condition, please do not suggest me to go for dynamic procedures. Other than that are welcome.

Comment: For 9, `Some_Condition` can be `1=1` or something that always evaluates to true

Answer (score 0):

You could add a couple of optional parameters that allow you to specify whether results should include Pending/Closed or Assigned/Unassigned results.  This way you maintain a single, flexible way of retrieving results.

Take a look at [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810663/60724) for an overview of using Optional Parameters in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

So, If i understand correctly, you can filter on two criteria independently. Option 1 is "Pending", "Closed" or "dont-filter", and option three is "Assigned", "Unassigned" and "dont-filter". "dont-filter" means that that criterion is not used in the filtering of items, i.e. the items returned can have any value for that parameter.

Combining these two filters you get your 3 X 3 = 9 possible scenarios.

What I would do is use the values of the parameters sent to the procedure to mold the query to my needs, along these lines:

```
create procedure getItems
   @Status int, -- 0 - don't filter, 1 - pending, 2 - closed
   @Assignment int -- 0 - don't filter, 1 - assigned, 2 - not assigned
as
begin
  select * from Items
  where ((@Status = 0) 
          and ((@Assignment = 0) -- no filter at all
              or (@Assignment = 1  and allocated_to is not null) 
              or (@Assignment = 2  and allocated_to is null)))
    or  ((@Status = 1 and pending is not null) 
          and ((@Assignment = 0) 
              or (@Assignment = 1  and allocated_to is not null) 
              or (@Assignment = 2  and allocated_to is null)))
   or  ((@Status = 2 and closed is not null) 
          and ((@Assignment = 0) 
              or (@Assignment = 1  and allocated_to is not null) 
              or (@Assignment = 2  and allocated_to is null)))
end
```

SQL Server is smart enough to use [parameter sniffing](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx) to optimize the actual query run, so basically, if you send `0, 0` as your parameters, the query will execute as

```
select * from Items
```

and if you send `1, 2` the query will execute as

```
select * from Items
where pending is not null
  and allocated_to is null
```

Comment: Your answer seems quite close enough to what I was looking for